# Why can't I use "this" in the Model (MVC Pattern)?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and to Java. I am wondering why I can't use "this" in the Model Class. I get the following error message: "incompatible types: Model cannot be converted to Context". The code works just fine if I write it in the Notes Class.
The error is down in the Model (where I create the Button, "this" is underlined in red in Android Studio).

```
package com.example.notesapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Controller controller;

    private EditText etNotesCreationHeader;
    private EditText etNotesCreationText;
    private Button btnNotesCreate;
    private Button btnNotesCreationCreate;
    private TextView tvNotesHeader;
    private TextView tvNotesCounter;

    public int counter;

    // נגדיר משתנה מסוג SharedPreferences
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    // כדי לכתוב ל Shared Preferences נגדיר Editor שלו
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

        sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(R.string.shared_preferences_file_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();

        initViews();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        tvNotesHeader.setText("Welcome back, " + name + "!");
        tvNotesCounter.setText("Number of Notes: " + sharedPref.getInt("counter", 0));

        counter = sharedPref.getInt("counter", -1);

    }

    private void initViews() {
        tvNotesHeader = findViewById(R.id.tvNotesHeader);
        tvNotesCounter = findViewById(R.id.tvNotesCounter);
        btnNotesCreate = findViewById(R.id.btnNotesCreate);
        etNotesCreationHeader = findViewById(R.id.etNotesCreationHeader);
        etNotesCreationText = findViewById(R.id.etNotesCreationText);
        btnNotesCreationCreate = findViewById(R.id.btnNotesCreationCreate);

        btnNotesCreate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNotesCreationCreate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnNotesCreate) {
            etNotesCreationHeader.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            etNotesCreationText.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            btnNotesCreationCreate.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Click 'Create' to finish!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (view == btnNotesCreationCreate) {
            if ((etNotesCreationText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) || etNotesCreationHeader.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //קטע יצירת הפתקים!
                etNotesCreationHeader.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                etNotesCreationText.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                btnNotesCreationCreate.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "The Note was created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                etNotesCreationHeader.setText("");
                etNotesCreationText.setText("");

                if (-1 == sharedPref.getInt("counter", -1)) {
                    counter = 0;
                    editor.putInt("counter", counter);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    counter += 1;
                    editor.putInt("counter", counter);
                    editor.commit();
                    tvNotesCounter.setText("Number of Notes: " + String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("counter", 0)));

                    this.controller.createNote();
                }
            }

            //כאן צריך להוסיף counter כדי שיוסיך ל-id של כל note מספר שונה, ובכך נשיג id ייחודי לכל note. בנוסף צריך להוסיף את ה-counter ל-shared preferences כדי שהוא תמיד יזכר על המכשיר ותמיד רק יגדל. ניתן להתשמש ב-id גם כשם במסמך של ה-shared preferences!
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.notesapplication;

public class Controller
{
    private Model model;

    public Controller() {
        this.model = new Model();
    }

    public void createNote() { this.model.createNote(); }
}
```

Model:

```
package com.example.notesapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Model {
    public void createNote() {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Evidently your `Notes` class extends `Context` and your `Model` class does not. You must be trying to use `this` for some purpose that requires an instance of `Context`.

Comment: How do I fix this? Sorry for the question, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the Button constructor must be an instance of `Context`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button#Button(android.content.Context)

Your `Notes` is a `Context` because it extends `AppCompatActivity`, and that (eventually) extends `Context`.

Your `Model` is not a `Context` because it does not extend any such type.

More to the point, in the MVC pattern, a button is inherently **not** part of your model. A model is the representation of information, not UI elements. So whatever idea has led you to think you need a Button inside your Model, you should probably rethink it.